# How do i automatically update a service reference at build time?

Tags: c#, wcf, msbuild-task

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Team Foundation Server 2013 update 4 and all the appropriate build services.

I have a .NET project that has references to several WCF services. What I would like to do is update the service references automatically as part of every build. Doing this process manually is no longer an option as it's far to time consuming so the idea is to automate this process. Target framework for the assembly has to 4.0.

Is this possible using a build task?

Comment: Wrap `svcutil` in a simple `<exec />` call will do that for you.You may need to explain Visual Studio to use the files on disk and not the files in it's hosted compiler cache: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2012/06/just-in-time-updating-of-source-files.html

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, maybe i should have mentioned i'm a bit of a noob to the whole TFS / Build Tasks..... any chance i could ask for you to post an example? including the command and any parameters

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the following as a pre-build event and it should generate the necessary files for you provided you have a connection to the server.

```
echo y | "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
cd %~dp0
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\svcutil.exe" http://localhost:8181/?wsdl
```